# IS NOT NULL test for a record does not return TRUE when variable is set

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, row, plpgsql

Using a plpgsql procedure to extract a record if it exists, and then if it does, do something with it.

The variable is a rowtype:

```
my_var my_table%rowtype;
```

I populate it with a SQL statement:

```
select * from my_table where owner_id = 6 into my_var;
```

I know it definitely has the row:

```
raise notice 'my_var is %', my_var;
```

Returns:

```
NOTICE:  my_var is (383,6,10)
```

But now I want to test that it got the record and BOTH of these if conditions fail:

```
if my_var is null then
  raise notice 'IT IS NULL';
end if;
if my_var is not null then
  raise notice 'IT IS NOT NULL';
end if;
```

Neither of these raises appear in my messages log - it just never enters the blocks.  What's the correct way to test if you received a row from a `SELECT * INTO`?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/7207923/1216680 ?

Comment: @Houari: You are linking to [a `plsql` question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7207923/1216680). That's for Oracle and not a duplicate. This one similar, but different. Also: a rather interesting question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I see two possible reasons, why ...

> Neither of these raises appear in my messages log

#### Not logged

Firstly, a `NOTICE` is not normally written to the database log with default settings. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-MIN-MESSAGES)

> `log_min_messages` (`enum`)
>
> Controls which message levels are written to the server log. Valid values are `DEBUG5`, `DEBUG4`, `DEBUG3`, `DEBUG2`, `DEBUG1`, `INFO`, `NOTICE`, `WARNING`, `ERROR`, `LOG`, `FATAL`, and `PANIC`. (...)
> The default is **WARNING**. Note that `LOG` has a different rank here than in `client_min_messages`.

Bold emphasis mine. Also note the different default (`NOTICE`) for `client_min_messages` (preceding item in the manual).

#### Invalid test

Secondly, consider how a row expression is evaluated. A test `row_variable IS NULL` returns `TRUE` if (and only if) *every single element* is `NULL`. Consider:

```
SELECT (1, NULL) IS NULL     AS a  -- FALSE
     , (1, NULL) IS NOT NULL AS b  -- also FALSE!
```

*Both* expressions return `FALSE`. In other words, a row (or record) variable `(1, NULL)` is neither `NULL`, nor is it `NOT NULL`. Therefore, both of your tests fail.

[**sqlfiddle** with more details](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/1138)

Related:

- [NOT NULL constraint over a set of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021102/not-null-constraint-over-a-set-of-columns/21026085#21026085)

You can even assign a record variable with NULL (`rec := NULL`), which results in every element being NULL - if the type is a well-known row type. Otherwise, we are dealing with an anonymous record and the structure is undefined and you cannot access elements to begin with. But that's not the case with a `rowtype` like in your example (which is always well-known).

#### Solution: `FOUND`

> What's the correct way to test if you received a row from a `SELECT * INTO`?

You have to consider that the row could be NULL, even if it was assigned. The query could very well have returned a bunch of NULL values (if the table definition in your query allows NULL values).

There is a simple and secure approach. Use `GET DIAGNOSTICS` or, where applicable, the special variable `FOUND`:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE owner_id = 6 INTO my_var;

IF NOT FOUND THEN
   RAISE NOTICE 'Query did not return a row!';
END IF;
```

[Details in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS)