# Extract column values from one table and insert with modifications into another

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I have created a PL/pgSQL function that accepts two column names, a "relation", and two table names. It finds distinct rows in one table and inserts them in to a temporary table, deletes any row with a null value, and sets all values of one column to `relation`. I have the first part of the process using this function.

```
create or replace function alt_edger(s text, v text, relation text, tbl text, tbl_src text)
    returns void
    language plpgsql as
$func$
begin
    raise notice 's: %, v: %, tbl: %, tbl_src: %', s,v,tbl,tbl_src;
    execute ('insert into '||tbl||' ("source", "target") select distinct "'||s||'","'||v||'" from '||tbl_src||'');
    execute ('DELETE FROM '||tbl||' WHERE "source" IS null or "target" is null'); 
end
$func$;
```

It is executed as follows:

```
-- create a temporary table and execute the function twice
drop table if exists temp_stack;
create temporary table temp_stack("label" text, "source" text, "target" text, "attr" text, "graph" text);
 
select alt_edger('x_x', 'y_y', ':associated_with', 'temp_stack','pg_check_table' );
select alt_edger('Document Number', 'x_x', ':documents', 'temp_stack','pg_check_table' );

select * from temp_stack;
```

Note that I didn't use `relation`, yet. The `INSERT` shall also assign `relation`, but I can't figure out how to make that happen to get something like:

| label | source | target | attr | graph |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| :associated_with | 638000 | ARAS |  |  |
| :associated_with | 202000 | JASE |  |  |
| :associated_with | 638010 | JASE |  |  |
| :associated_with | 638000 | JASE |  |  |
| :associated_with | 202100 | JASE |  |  |
| :documents | A | 638010 |  |  |
| :documents | A | 202000 |  |  |
| :documents | A | 202100 |  |  |
| :documents | B | 638000 |  |  |
| :documents | A | 638000 |  |  |
| :documents | B | 124004 |  |  |
| :documents | B | 202100 |  |  |

My challenges are:

- How to integrate `relation` in  the `INSERT`?  When I try to use  `VALUES` and comma separation I get an "error near select".
- How to allow strings starting with  ":" in `relation`? I'm anticipating here, the inclusion of the colon has given me challenges in the past.

How can I do this? Or is there a better approach?

**Toy data model**:

```
drop table if exists pg_check_table;
create temporary table pg_check_table("Document Number" text, x_x int, y_y text);
insert into pg_check_table values ('A',202000,'JASE'),
('A',202100,'JASE'),
('A',638010,'JASE'),
('A',Null,'JASE'),
('A',Null,'JASE'),
('A',202100,'JASE'),
('A',638000,'JASE'),
('A',202100,'JASE'),
('B',638000,'JASE'),
('B',202100,null),
('B',638000,'JASE'),
('B',null,'ARAS'),
('B',638000,'ARAS'),
('B',null,'ARAS'),
('B',638000,null),
('B',124004,null);
alter table pg_check_table add row_num serial;
select * from pg_check_table;
```

Comment: What have you tried, and did you run into any errors ? pls share more details.

Comment: @Anand: This question shares useful details. Way above average.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
-- DROP FUNCTION alt_edger(_s text, _v text, _relation text, _tbl text, _tbl_src text)
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION alt_edger(_s text, _v text, _relation text, _tbl text, _tbl_src text, OUT row_count int)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _sql text := format(
       'INSERT INTO pg_temp.%3$I (label, source, target)
        SELECT DISTINCT $1, %1$I, %2$I FROM pg_temp.%4$I
        WHERE (%1$I, %2$I) IS NOT NULL'
      , _s, _v, _tbl, _tbl_src);
BEGIN
   -- RAISE NOTICE '%', _sql;  -- debug
   EXECUTE _sql USING _relation;
   GET DIAGNOSTICS row_count = ROW_COUNT;  -- return number of inserted rows
END
$func$;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e81608df86ce72d90536ace3dccfc546)*

Most importantly, use [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) to concatenate your dynamic SQL commands safely. And use the format specifier `%I` for identifiers. This way, SQL injection is not possible and identifiers are double-quoted properly - preserving non-standard names like `Document Number`. That's where your original failed.

We *could* concatenate `_relation` as string to be inserted into `label`, too. But the preferable way to pass *values* to `EXECUTE` is with the `USING` clause. `$1` inside the SQL string passed to `EXECUTE` is a placeholder for the first `USING` argument. Not to be confused with `$1` referencing function parameters in the context of the function body *outside* `EXECUTE`! (You can pass *any* string, leading colon (`:`) does not matter, the string is not interpreted when done right.)
See:

- [Format specifier for integer variables in format() for EXECUTE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22656716/format-specifier-for-integer-variables-in-format-for-execute/22675836#22675836)
- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)

I replaced the `DELETE` in your original with a `WHERE` clause to the `SELECT` of the `INSERT`. Don't insert rows in the first place, instead of deleting them again later.

`(%1$I, %2$I) IS NOT NULL` only qualifies when both values are `NOT NULL`.
About that:

- [Check if a Postgres composite field is null/empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22763151/check-if-a-postgres-composite-field-is-null-empty/22764076#22764076)

Don't use the prefix "pg_" for your table names. That's what Postgres uses for [system tables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalogs.html). Don't mess with those.

I schema-qualify known temporary tables with `pg_temp.` That's typically optional as the temporary schema comes first in the `search_path` by default. But that can be changed (maliciously), and then the table name would resolve to any existing regular table of the same name in the `search_path`. So better safe than sorry. See:

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema/9067777#9067777)

I made the function return the number of inserted rows. That's totally optional!
Since I do that with an `OUT` parameter, I am allowed to skip the `RETURNS` clause. See:

- [Can I make a plpgsql function return an integer without using a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169676/can-i-make-a-plpgsql-function-return-an-integer-without-using-a-variable/8169928#8169928)