# plpgsql - using dynamic table name in declare statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to write plpgsql a function of the following form (note this is a simplified version):

```
CREATE FUNCTION check_valid(tablename regclass) RETURNS boolean AS $$

DECLARE valid_row tablename%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN

EXECUTE format('SELECT * FROM %s', tablename) into valid_row;

IF valid_row IS NULL THEN
      RETURN QUERY SELECT false;

ELSIF valid_row.is_valid = false;
      RETURN QUERY SELECT false;

ELSIF valid_row.hit_count > valid_row.hit_limit;
      RETURN QUERY SELECT false;

ELSE
      RETURN QUERY SELECT true;

END IF;

END

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The part that's failing is the `DECLARE` line. How can I declare a type based on a variable table name? Or perhaps I need to cast it somehow?

Something like `DECLARE mytable%ROWTYPE;` works fine, yet if I use a variable name like `tablename%ROWTYPE`:

`ERROR:  relation "tablename" does not exist`

Comment: I think declaring it as `record` should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's important to understand the principal nature of these five **different kinds of data / symbol**:

#### 1. `'my_tbl'`

A string literal of **`unknown` type**. When used in SQL (embedded in plpgsql code or not), it is coerced to a type derived from the **context**. If the type cannot be determined an explicit cast may be required. Like: `'my_tbl'::text`.

#### 2. `'my_tbl'::text`

The same string literal cast to **type `text`**. It can hold the name of a table, but it's really just text.

#### 3. `'my_tbl'::regclass`

An **[object identifier (OID)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-oid.html) for a registered *class***. It is displayed and can be input as string representing a valid object name (`'my_tbl'`). The output is automatically schema-qualified (`'my_schema.my_tbl'`) and / or double-quoted (`'"mY_TbL"'`) if it would be ambiguous or illegal otherwise. It can be a regular *table*, *sequence*, *view*, *materialized view*, *composite type* etc. Details in this related answer:

- [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582500/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-a-given-schema/24089729#24089729)

#### 4. `my_tbl_var my_tbl` (short for `my_tbl_var my_tbl%ROWTYPE`)

In the `DECLARE` section of a plpgsql code block that's a variable declaration with a **well known [row type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-ROWTYPES)** (a.k.a. composite type). The type has to be registered in the system table `pg_class` (same as with a `regclass` variable). It's not the OID of the referenced object, but its actual row type. `my_tbl_var` and `my_tbl` are both *identifiers* here and cannot be parameterized. You can also cast any row or record directly: `(123, 'foo')::my_tbl`

#### 5. `my_tbl_var record`

In the `DECLARE` section of a plpgsql code block that's the declaration of an **anonymous [record](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-RECORDS)**. Basically, a placeholder for a yet unknown row type / with yet undefined structure. It can be used in *most* of the places a row type can be used. But you cannot access fields from it before the record variable is assigned.

You were confusing **1.**, **3.** and **4.** and solved it by using **5.** instead.
But there is **more going wrong** here:

- You are selecting a whole table, but a row (record) variable can only hold one row at a time. So only the first is assigned and returned. While there is no `ORDER BY` clause, the result is arbitrary and can change any time. **Evil trap.**
- Since you are now using a `record` type, you need to make sure it has been assigned before you can run tests on its fields, or you'll get exceptions for empty tables.
  In your case the check `record_var IS NULL` almost does the same job. But there is a corner case for rows with NULL in all fields: then `record_var IS NULL` evaluates to true. Even trickier for the test `IS NOT NULL`. Details here:

  - [IS NOT NULL test for a record does not return TRUE when variable is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21765198/is-not-null-test-for-a-record-does-not-return-true-when-variable-is-set/21770324#21770324)

  I added a demo to the [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/40b34/2) below.
- The function returns a single scalar (`boolean`) value. Use:

  ```
  RETURN false;
  ```

  Instead of:

  ```
  RETURN QUERY SELECT false;
  ```

### Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION check_valid(_tbl regclass)
  RETURNS bool AS
$func$
DECLARE
   r record;
   _row_ct int;
BEGIN
   EXECUTE '
   SELECT is_valid, hit_count, hit_limit
   FROM  ' || _tbl || '
   ORDER  <whatever>
   LIMIT  1'            -- replace <whatever> with your sort criteria
   INTO r;              -- only needed columns

   GET DIAGNOSTICS _row_ct = ROW_COUNT;

   IF _row_ct = 0 THEN  -- necessary, because r may not be assigned
      RETURN false;
   ELSIF NOT r.is_valid OR r.hit_count > r.hit_limit THEN
      RETURN false;
   END IF;

   RETURN true;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/40b34/2) (with two variants of the function and a demo for row IS NULL).

#### Major points

- Use [`GET DIAGNOSTICS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS) to find out whether any rows were found in a dynamic statement with `EXECUTE`.
- The `IF` expression can be simplified.
- The parameter is of type `regclass`, not just a tablename. I wouldn't use the misleading name "tablename" for this parameter. That only adds to your initial confusion. Calling it `_tbl` instead.

If you'd want to also *return* a set of variable row type:

- [Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557)

Comment: Great answer, and very details. Just an update on the function - the one I'd given as I said was over simplified. I'm actually already returning a row (not a boolean) and that's why I was using `RETURN QUERY SELECT false, some_val, r.something, r.something else`. So you're also saying that a check for `IF r IS NULL` is not good enough, and I need to check the row count? Finally I need the separate `ELSIF` statements, since as I said, I'm returning a row other than just a single variable, which varies for each case. Thanks nonetheless!

Comment: @Patrick: I had a feeling the demo was over-simplified. The check `r IS NULL` is almost good. But there is a corner case, so it's better to use `GET DIAGNOSTICS`, to be sure. I added a bit to my answer and fiddle.

Comment: Cheers for the extra explanation and +1 for the other SO links. I know in my case that a) I will only be getting unique rows (always either 1 or no rows) and b) that if a row exists it will not be NULL, but you're right nonetheless

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by a_horse_with_no_name - using:

`DECLARE valid_row RECORD;`

works :)