# How do I use variables in a postgresql function for loop query

Tags: postgresql, function, for-loop, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I have a rather complicated function in postgresql (Version 9.4.4) that I need a bit of help with.

I have a loop (with lots of work below) declared like this inside of my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function getRSI(
    psymbol varchar,
    pstarttime timestamp with time zone,
    pendtime timestamp with time zone,
    pduration double precision,
    ptable varchar
    )
 RETURNS SETOF rsi AS
 $BODY$
 declare
    row_data record;
    -- some variables
 begin
    FOR row_data IN SELECT datetime, value FROM "4" WHERE symbol = 'AAPL' 
    AND datetime BETWEEN '2015-11-23 09:30:00 -0500' AND 
    '2015-11-23 15:59:59-0500' LOOP
       -- enter code here
    END LOOP;
 end
 $BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

This works perfectly, I can get the result of my function and have it crunch all the numbers for me.

I would like to get the loop to work like this:

```
FOR row_data in select datetime, value from quote_ident(ptable) 
where symbol = quote_literal(psymbol) and datetime 
between quote_literal(pstarttime) AND quote_literal(pendtime) LOOP
```

where `ptable`, `psymbol`, `pstarttime` and `pendtime` are variables passed from the function call.

But I would be happy having to hardcode a table and getting the other three things to be based on a variable:

```
FOR row_data in select datetime, value from "4" where symbol =
quote_literal(psymbol) and datetime between quote_literal(pstarttime)
AND quote_literal(pendtime) LOOP
```

Yes, I know that I have a table named after a number, nothing I can do about it in my current setup.

When I try to call the function with either of the above setups, I just get a blank. Any help would be appreciated. I can't find any documentation about using a variable in a for loop so it might not be possible.

Comment: You should provide a complete (minimal) function. The complete header and declarations matter. And always your version of Postgres.

Comment: @Erwin appreciate that feedback, I updated the question even though you already perfectly answered it for me. Thank you!

Comment: `row_data` should be declared as `record`. I took the liberty to round it off.

Comment: I didn't realize that I could use a record. I had created a specific type for the results of the query based on another stack example of a loop I had found. Much more readable using the record. Thanks (again!)

Comment: I added a link to the manual.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE` - but *only* to parameterize the table name (or other identifiers) - not necessary to parameterize *values*.

And do *not* concatenate parameter values into the query. That's more expensive and error prone than necessary. Use the [`USING` clause of `EXECUTE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING) instead.

```
FOR row_data IN
   EXECUTE '
    SELECT datetime, value FROM ' || quote_ident(ptable) || '
    WHERE  symbol = $1
    AND    datetime between $2 AND $3'
   USING psymbol, pstarttime, pendtime
LOOP
  -- do stuff
END LOOP;
```

Or use [`format()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT):

```
   EXECUTE format('
    SELECT datetime, value FROM %I 
    WHERE  symbol = $1
    AND    datetime between $2 AND $3', ptable)
   USING psymbol, pstarttime, pendtime
```

Related:

- [The manual on `record` types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-RECORDS)
- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)
- [plpgsql - using dynamic table name in declare statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26847537/plpgsql-using-dynamic-table-name-in-declare-statement/26856561#26856561)

Comment: @Erwin, in the above line, shouldn't we also add concatenation pipes right before the quote_ident part, like this?: SELECT datetime, value FROM ' || quote_ident(ptable) || '

Answer (score 1):

change your for loop like this

```
FOR row_data in execute 'select datetime, value from "4" where symbol =' || 
quote_literal(psymbol)  || 'and datetime between' || quote_literal(pstarttime)
|| 'AND ' || quote_literal(pendtime) LOOP
```

Comment: You are my new favorite person! Aside from changing the end from `quote_literal(pendtime) || 'LOOP'` to `quote_literal(pendtime) LOOP` that worked perfectly! I spent like an hour googling how to do that before I finally gave up and asked.

Comment: Thanks... @BenHernandez