# How to execute SQL code with concatenated table name?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

An example of what I am attempting to do:

```
SELECT  count(*) as "count" 
FROM (
   SELECT overlay('db_xx.company_summary' placing 'US' from 4)
) as s
```

This returns count to be 1, while there are many rows in the table `db_us.company_summary`.
I would expect it to count all rows, similar to this query:

```
SELECT count(*) as "count" 
FROM   db_us.company_summary
```

I attempted the overlay function, to be similar to the above query. I am not sure if its possible to do this in SQL.

In Python you would do something like this:

```py
"hello {}".format("world")
```

So I would like the input string to act as a SQL syntax command.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Normally your RDBMS might support dynamic SQL, using which you can execute a query from a string (so you build the query string with whatever substitutions you would like and pass it to execute)

Comment: I understand this, but I just don't know how. Am I asking a question that is not possible to solve using a simple SQL function? I'm not sure.

Comment: `select overlay('db_xx.company_summary' ..)` returns a single row with a single string value. Why do you expect that to return anything else? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=807a20a72b3d20323d90ed1cff710376

Comment: I was just painting a picture what I wanted to do. Obviously it doesn't translate.

Comment: You can use an approach like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38684225/330315) if you need to do the count with dynamic SQL.

Comment: thanks @a_horse_with_no_name this looks promising. 
Will comeback.

Comment: So do you have your answer?

Answer (score 2):

Plain SQL does not allow to parameterize identifiers (or *anything* but values). You need **dynamic SQL**. Examples:

- [Truncating all tables in a Postgres database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829158/truncating-all-tables-in-a-postgres-database/12082038#12082038)
- [How to use variable as table name in plpgsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35559093/how-to-use-variable-as-table-name-in-plpgsql/35642628#35642628)
- [How do I use variables in a postgresql function for loop query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34526233/how-do-i-use-variables-in-a-postgresql-function-for-loop-query/34526509#34526509)

Example PL/pgSQL function with dynamic SQL:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_counts()
  RETURNS SETOF bigint
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _lower_iso2 text;
   _ct bigint;
BEGIN
   FOR _lower_iso2 IN
      SELECT lower(iso2) FROM country_code
   LOOP
      RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
      format ('SELECT count(*) AS count FROM %I.company_summary'
            , overlay('db_xx' PLACING _lower_iso2 FROM 4)
             );
   END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_counts();
```

Result:

```
f_counts
---------
2
3
4
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5d1dabab68509ff24dfced5acf710fe4)*

Be aware that Postgres identifiers are case sensitive:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)