# how to check if a record is null

Tags: oracle, plsql, record

I have a procedure which receives a record as an IN parameter (the procedure also has an OUT parameter.)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE p
  PROCEDURE p_select( p_filter_params IN t_filter_params
                    , p_order_list OUT SYS_REFCURSOR);
END p;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY p
  PROCEDURE p_select( p_filter_params IN t_filter_params
                    , p_order_list OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS
  BEGIN
    IF p_filter_params IS NULL
      THEN
        NULL;
    END IF;
  END p_select,
END p;
```

executable section

```
DECLARE
  TYPE t_filter_params IS RECORD
    ( f_name    customers.cust_first_name%TYPE
    , l_name    customers.cust_last_name%TYPE
    , city      customers.cust_address.city%TYPE
    , from_date orders.order_date%TYPE
    , to_date   orders.order_date%TYPE);

  vr_params t_filter_params;

  TYPE ref_cursor IS REF CURSOR;

  v_cursor ref_cursor;

BEGIN
  /*vr_params.f_name := 'john';
  vr_params.l_name := 'smith';
  vr_params.city := 'Dallas';
  vr_params.from_date := SYSDATE - 100;
  vr_params.to_date := SYSDATE;*/

  --p.p_select(vr_params, v_cursor);
  p.p_select(null, v_cursor);
end;
```

Can someone tell me how to make it work the IF statement from procedure, please?

Thank you very much,
Mikcutu.

Comment: what is the problem? How can it work if you pass a not-null value to the procedure?

Comment: @smnbbrv: sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: you are asking whether the record is null or not. BUT. You pass a record which is definitely `NOT NULL` here `p.p_select(vr_params, v_cursor);`. So question is, why do you expect your `if` to be working?

Comment: the procedure might be call as `p.p_select(null, v_cursor);`

Comment: but you don't call it that way, do you? You are posting a question, so, please, be precise everywhere. This is confusing

Comment: I updated the code as per real use

Comment: You cannot define a type in a PL/SQL anonymous block and use it in a package/procedure. You need to define it in either a package or in the SQL scope.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check a record IS NOT NULL in plsql](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7207894/1509264).

Answer (score 2):

Records are somehow special. If you set a record to `null` all the record properties are set to null, but the record itself still exists.

The first thing that comes to my mind is either checking if some sort of `id` is null on the record - that would mean the record is empty.

You don't have an id, but this could lead to another solution: adding another property which is null whenever it is not filled.

The third approach: just go through every property and check whether every property `is null`.

And finally, the best, reject using `RECORD` and use `OBJECT` instead: it works exactly as you expect it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can not:

```
SQL> create or replace package p is
  2      type tType is record ( a number, b number);
  3      --
  4      procedure proc(pIn IN tType);
  5  end;
  6  /

Package created.

SQL> create or replace package body p is
  2      procedure proc(pIn IN tType) is
  3      begin
  4          if pIn is null then
  5              dbms_output.put_line('NULL');
  6          else
  7              dbms_output.put_line('NOT NULL');
  8          end if;
  9      end;
 10  end;
 11  /

Warning: Package Body created with compilation errors.

SQL> sho err
Errors for PACKAGE BODY P:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
4/9      PL/SQL: Statement ignored
4/12     PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'IS
         NULL'
```

With a slightly different approach, you could use a schema-level type:

```
SQL> create or replace type tType is object ( a number, b number);
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace package p2 is
  2      --
  3      procedure proc(pIn IN tType);
  4  end;
  5  /

Package created.

SQL> create or replace package body p2 is
  2      procedure proc(pIn IN tType) is
  3      begin
  4          if pIn  is null then
  5              dbms_output.put_line('NULL');
  6          else
  7              dbms_output.put_line('NOT NULL');
  8          end if;
  9      end;
 10  end;
 11  /

Package body created.

SQL>
```

Comment: In the first example you can get it to work using a local record type but you must refer to each individual component of the type rather than the type itself, e.g. IF pIn.f_name is NULL THEN . . . .

Answer (score 1):

Don't complicate things passing a record, just pass the individual parameters:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE p
AS
  PROCEDURE p_select(
    in_f_name    customers.cust_first_name%TYPE
  , in_l_name    customers.cust_last_name%TYPE
  , in_city      customers.cust_address.city%TYPE
  , in_from_date orders.order_date%TYPE
  , in_to_date   orders.order_date%TYPE
  , out_order_list OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
  );
END p;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY p
AS
  PROCEDURE p_select(
    in_f_name    customers.cust_first_name%TYPE
  , in_l_name    customers.cust_last_name%TYPE
  , in_city      customers.cust_address.city%TYPE
  , in_from_date orders.order_date%TYPE
  , in_to_date   orders.order_date%TYPE
  , out_order_list OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
  ) AS
  BEGIN
    OPEN out_order_list FOR
    SELECT *
    FROM   orders o INNER JOIN customers c ON ( o.customer_id = c.customer_id )
    WHERE  ( in_f_name IS NULL OR c.cust_first_name = in_f_name )
    OR     ( in_l_name IS NULL OR c.cust_last_name  = in_l_name )
    OR     ( in_city   IS NULL OR c.cust_address.city = in_city )
    OR     ( in_from_date IS NULL OR o.order_date >= in_from_date )
    OR     ( in_to_date   IS NULL OR o.order_date <= in_to_date );
  END p_select,
END p;
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to work with reverse logic. It is e.g. not possible to ask:

```
IF my_record IS NULL THEN
   do something;
END IF;
```

or

```
IF my_record.my_attibute IS NULL THEN
   do something;
END IF;
```

Instead it is possible to ask:

```
IF my_record.my_attibute IS NOT NULL THEN
   go on processing;
ELSE
   do something;
END IF;
```